# Column with random, increasing numbers in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random

I have a dataframe of about 10,000 rows. Each record includes a Recordid and an integer that represents the number of days since the start for that RecordID. For example:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame( { 
"RecordID" : ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5" , "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5" ] , 
"number_of_days" : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]})
df
RecordID    number_of_days
0   id1     1
1   id2     1
2   id3     1
3   id4     1
4   id5     1
5   id1     2
6   id2     2
7   id3     2
8   id4     2
9   id5     2
```

I'd like to add a column that contains a random number between 1 and 100. But I need the random to be *higher* than the previous random value for each ID. This is an example of what I would like to get:

```
RecordID    number_of_days  random_value
0   id1     1               10
1   id1     2               13
2   id1     3               45
3   id1     4               50
4   id1     5               62
5   id1     6               80
6   id1     7               81
7   id1     8               82
8   id1     9               92
9   id1     10              99
10  id2     2               12
11  id2     4               31
```

I see posts about creating a field with random values. I'm not finding any that address the need for generating random values that increase, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate all random numbers, slice it properly based on the group sizes, sort each slice, and assign back. First we need to sort the DataFrame so that assignment occurs properly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df.sort_values('RecordID')

arr = np.array_split(np.random.randint(1, 100, len(df)),
                     df.groupby('RecordID').size().cumsum()[:-1])

df['Random_Value'] = np.sort(arr, axis=1).ravel()
```

#### Output

```
  RecordID  number_of_days  Random_Value
0      id1               1            19
5      id1               2            41
1      id2               1            53
6      id2               2            56
2      id3               1            33
7      id3               2            68
3      id4               1            57
8      id4               2            67
4      id5               1            39
9      id5               2            49
```

---

As always, it's best to avoid `groupby.apply(lambda x: ...` as this is a slow loop over the groups.

```
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({"RecordID": list(range(N))*10,
                   "number_of_days": np.repeat(range(10), N)})

def ALollz(df):
    df = df.sort_values(['RecordID', 'number_of_days'])

    arr = np.array_split(np.random.randint(1, 100, len(df)),
                         df.groupby('RecordID').size().cumsum()[:-1])

    df['Random_Value'] = np.sort(arr, axis=1).ravel()

    return df

%timeit ALollz(df)
#54 ms ± 1.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.assign(random_value=df.groupby('RecordID').transform(lambda x: np.sort(np.random.randint(1,100, len(x))))).sort_values('RecordID')
#15.9 s ± 124 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.groupby('RecordID').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sort(np.random.randint(1,100, len(x))))).reset_index()
#1.23 s ± 25.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This worked well. One small change: For df.sort_values, I included number_of_days --  df.sort_values(['RecordID','number_of_days'). That seems to get me the desired outcome.

Answer (score 5):

You can generate random numbers, sort and then assign to df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { 

"RecordID" : ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5" , "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5" ] , 
"number_of_days" : [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]})

df['random_value'] = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,100, len(df)))


    RecordID    number_of_days  random_value
0   id1         1               5
1   id2         1               7
2   id3         1               19
3   id4         1               34
4   id5         1               45
5   id1         2               53
6   id2         2               67
7   id3         2               72
8   id4         2               72
9   id5         2               80
```

Edit: If you want the random_value by group, you can group data by ID and then assign sorted random numbers,

```
df.groupby('RecordID').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.sort(np.random.randint(1,100, len(x))))).reset_index(name = 'random_value')
```

Comment: I think a groupby is needed.

Answer (score 0):

this sentence `the random to be higher than the previous random value for each ID` leads me to understand that there is no duplicates allow in the random numbers of each unique `ID`. As I understand, `np.random.randint` will generate random numbers without any option to prevent duplicates, so I came up with solution using `tranform` and `np.random.choice`.

```
np.random.seed(0) #For showing consistent output. Take this line out in production.
s = (df.groupby('RecordID')
       .RecordID
       .transform(lambda x: np.sort(np.random.choice(np.arange(1,100), 
                                                     x.shape[0], replace=False))))

Out[262]:
0      3
1     17
2     27
3     55
4     56
5     74
6     76
7     87
8     93
9     95
10    19
11    30
Name: RecordID, dtype: int32

df['random_value'] = s    

Out[264]:
   RecordID  number_of_days  random_value
0       id1               1             3
1       id1               2            17
2       id1               3            27
3       id1               4            55
4       id1               5            56
5       id1               6            74
6       id1               7            76
7       id1               8            87
8       id1               9            93
9       id1              10            95
10      id2               2            19
11      id2               4            30
```